# When connecting via com port, it doesnt ask login and password

Tags: port-channel

I have successfully connected to Alcatel OmniPCX device via Serial COM port with help of XShell program to config interface. 
It says that it is connected. It doesn's ask for login and password.  
But I have to write login and password to continue my configuration. 
How and where can I write my login and password? 
Thank you guys!

Comment: Please paste the output of this command: show aaa authentication

Comment: @Mr.lock, the problem was in cable. It needed specific cable, which after that loaded its bios and asked for login and password.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.